# JavaScript function doesn't seem to work consistently

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs2

I'm trying to create a dynamic menu that only displays certain questions if the previous question has been answered. I've got it to work for one of the questions, but the next one throws the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`, even though the code is virtually identical.

Here's the JavaScript function I'm calling:

```js
// displays div when input is not empty
function showOnInput(div, input) {
    let x = document.getElementById(`${input}`);
    let y = document.getElementById(`${div}`);
    if (x.value.length > 0) {
        y.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        y.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

and here's the HTML code it's being called in:

```html
<div id="customizeChar" class="text">
    <form>
    <div id="name">
        <label>What is your character's name?</label>
        <br>
        <input v-model="fname" id="fname" placeholder="First Name" onkeyup="showOnInput('age', 'fname')">
        <input v-model="lname" id="lname" placeholder="Last Name">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="age" style="display: none">
        <label>How old is {{fname}} {{lname}}?</label>
        <br>
        <input v-model="age" id="age" placeholder="Age" onkeyup="showOnInput('sex', 'age')">
        <label style="font-size: 80%">years old</label>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <div id="sex" style="display: none">
        <label>Is {{fname}} a male or female?</label>
        <br>
        <select v-model="sex">
            <option>Male</option>
            <option>Female</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

The `age` block is hidden until an input is given in the `name` block, as expected, but inputting an answer in the `age` block then throws the `Uncaught TypeError` error.

Comment: Don't see why you can't debug the code. The error message is pretty clear. you pass two ids to the function and at least one of them looks up an element which has no `value` property

Comment: The input should have a value, though, which is what the function is checking for.

Comment: @lexith `<input>` doesn't have a value attribute?

Comment: @TheHeadRush is this what i wrote? maybe read again.

Comment: If you are using `Vue` you shouldn't be modifying the dom this way. You should be using `v-if` and methods that are triggered on the component.

Comment: @lexith I think it is what you wrote. `x` is the html element with an id of "age"`. which is an `<input>` which should have a `value` attribute.

Comment: @TheHeadRush ^^ i said "an element". not input. as i see it he tries to get an input element but doesn't therefore the error msg `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`.

Comment: @MarkMeyer I'm fairly new to Vue (this is actually the first project I've ever done with it) so I don't know my way around it all that well. ~Is `v-if`in the Vue documentation? I haven't come across it yet if it is.~ Never mind, just found it.

Comment: @DCoded yes it's all well-documented: [Conditional Rendering](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html). It will allow you to show blocks based on data in your component. You could for example use `v-if="age"`.

Comment: @lexith If no element had `id="age"` the error would be `cannot read property 'value' of undefined`, no?

Comment: @TheHeadRush what are you on about? i clearly said he looks up an element which has no `value` property therefore the error message. sure if he wouldn't find any element it would be `blala 'value' of undefined` but it isn't. so his element query obviously returns something different. Maybe it has something to do with the fact that there are multiple elements with id `age`... now sit back and think twice before you respond again

Comment: @lexith There's only one element with the ID `age`.

Comment: then take a look at the `<div id="age" style="display: none">` part and the input with the same id.

Comment: @lexith Seems like pointing out that the `id` was not unique would have been preferable to making people guess what you mean. In any case, enjoy your day.

Comment: @TheHeadRush matter of principle. i voted to close the question and gave a short comment to hint in the right direction instead of an answer because i don't see any effort by OP to his "problem". a simple `console.log(x, y)` would have solved this. there is a specific entry in the "close question"-popup that covers this. Anyway, a good day to you as well.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to do what I wanted using Vue's `v-if` directive. Here's the final HTML:

```html
<div id="customizeChar" class="text">
    <form>
    <div id="name">
        <label>What is your character's name?</label>
        <br>
        <input v-model="fname" id="fname" placeholder="First Name">
        <input v-model="lname" id="lname" placeholder="Last Name">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="age" v-if="fname != ''">
        <label>How old is {{fname}} {{lname}}?</label>
        <br>
        <input v-model="age" id="age" placeholder="Age">
        <label style="font-size: 80%">years old</label>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <div id="sex" v-if="age != ''">
        <label>Is {{fname}} a male or female?</label>
        <br>
        <select v-model="sex">
            <option>Male</option>
            <option>Female</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Let me know if there are improvements I can make.